# CAS on confluence TicketValidationException

Tags: single-sign-on, cas, confluence

Hi am trying to create a Staging Server for Confluence and I cloned the VM and updated Confluence settings. Now after login I get

```
    javax.servlet.ServletException: org.jasig.cas.client.validation.TicketValidationException: 
            ticket 'ST-224-7T1R0Olcgf3BJfvwOjJ3-cas' not recognized
Referer URL

https://sso.server.com:8445/cas/login?service=https%3A%2F%2F10.1.1.59%3A8443%2Fhomepage.action
```

The original Confluence still works but the Staging one errors our.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug but there is a workaround. See: http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/13347927 .

Summary:

1. Disable the Terms of Use (Control Panel > Portal Settings > Users >
   Terms of Use Required)
2. Disable the password reminder query. Put the
       line `users.reminder.queries.enabled=false` in the file
       portal-ext.properties .

I had the same problem as you, tried this recipe and it worked. Good luck!